# Как вычленить число из строки в столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Дана [таблица](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mEZHj6yOqaC0d6agpm-kiP-X6aBYBoI0?usp=sharing), необходимо для каждого направления ветра - СЗ, С, ЮВ, Ю и т.д. подсчитать скорость ветра (сумма по направлениям за месяц). Не знаю, как это сделать, как вычленить число да еще сохранить его в переменной, чтоб подсчитать сумму.

```
def sever_vostok(file):
    global sv
    for i in range(len(file)):
        if file.loc[i]['Ветер днем'].split('')[0]=='CВ':
            sv+=int(file.loc[i]['Ветер днем'].split('')[-1][:-3])
```

где функции передается csv файл с таблицей.
Чтобы не делать 16 функций для каждого направления, как оптимизировать код? помогите, пожалуйста
[image: таблица]

Comment: Пример исходных данных в воспроизводимом виде приведите. Зачем нам ваш скириншот?

Comment: Извините, Вам файл скинуть?

Comment: Вы можете в вопросе указать ссылку на файл для скачивания. Например на Google Drive или файлообменник. И еще, что значит "подсчитать сумму"? каким должен быть результат? Как вы его видите?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mEZHj6yOqaC0d6agpm-kiP-X6aBYBoI0?usp=sharing

Comment: С=сумма скорости северного ветра за месяц

Comment: ЮВ=сумма скорости юго-восточного направления за месяц

Comment: и тд для всех направлений

Comment: в папке любой файл можно взять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), чтобы создать отдельные колонки для направления и скорости, затем сгруппировать по направлению и посчитать сумму скоростей для каждого направления.

Датафрейм `kazan_1998_2.csv`:

```
    Unnamed: 0 Ветер вечером Ветер днём  Давление вечером  Давление днём  День  Температура вечером  Температура днём
0            0       ЮВ 6м/с    ЮВ 6м/с               748            742     1                  -15               -10
1            1        З 5м/с     З 5м/с               756            748     2                  -24               -18
2            2        Ю 3м/с     Ю 3м/с               763            756     3                  -20               -22
3            3      ЮВ 12м/с   ЮВ 12м/с               748            748     4                  -12               -13
4            4        З 9м/с     З 9м/с               749            741     5                  -16               -13
5            5        С 2м/с     С 2м/с               756            747     6                  -18               -15
6            6       СВ 5м/с    СВ 5м/с               762            754     7                  -24               -19
7            7             Ш          Ш               762            757     8                  -21               -20
8            8        Ю 9м/с     Ю 9м/с               752            750     9                   -8                -7
9            9        З 7м/с     З 7м/с               753            746    10                   -8                -3
10          10       З 11м/с    З 11м/с               738            731    11                    0                 2
11          11        З 8м/с     З 8м/с               732            729    12                   -7                -1
12          12        С 8м/с     С 8м/с               742            735    13                  -25               -23
13          13       СЗ 8м/с    СЗ 8м/с               746            739    14                  -27               -26
14          14       СЗ 6м/с    СЗ 6м/с               753            744    15                  -26               -24
15          15        Ю 7м/с     Ю 7м/с               744            747    16                  -19               -22
16          16        В 4м/с     В 4м/с               736            728    17                  -20               -17
17          17       СЗ 8м/с    СЗ 8м/с               750            742    18                  -21               -21
18          18       Ю 10м/с    Ю 10м/с               735            734    19                  -17               -17
19          19       СЗ 9м/с    СЗ 9м/с               748            736    20                  -16               -11
20          20       ЮЗ 3м/с    ЮЗ 3м/с               759            753    21                  -14               -14
21          21        З 7м/с     З 7м/с               750            746    22                    1                 1
22          22       С 10м/с    С 10м/с               753            743    25                  -15               -12
23          23        С 5м/с     С 5м/с               761            756    26                  -17               -15
24          24        Ю 9м/с     Ю 9м/с               752            750    27                   -8               -10
25          25        Ю 8м/с     Ю 8м/с               746            742    28                    0                -3
```

Решение:

```
# Разобъем столбец 'Ветер вечером' на 2 отдельных - направление и скорость
df[['Направление', 'Скорость']] = df['Ветер вечером'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
# Очищаем 'Скорость'
df['Скорость'] = df['Скорость'].str.replace('м/с', '').fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Получились такие столбцы:

```
    Unnamed: 0 Ветер вечером Ветер днём  Давление вечером  ...  Температура вечером  Температура днём  Направление  Скорость
0            0       ЮВ 6м/с    ЮВ 6м/с               748  ...                  -15               -10           ЮВ         6
1            1        З 5м/с     З 5м/с               756  ...                  -24               -18            З         5
2            2        Ю 3м/с     Ю 3м/с               763  ...                  -20               -22            Ю         3
3            3      ЮВ 12м/с   ЮВ 12м/с               748  ...                  -12               -13           ЮВ        12
4            4        З 9м/с     З 9м/с               749  ...                  -16               -13            З         9
5            5        С 2м/с     С 2м/с               756  ...                  -18               -15            С         2
6            6       СВ 5м/с    СВ 5м/с               762  ...                  -24               -19           СВ         5
7            7             Ш          Ш               762  ...                  -21               -20            Ш         0
8            8        Ю 9м/с     Ю 9м/с               752  ...                   -8                -7            Ю         9
9            9        З 7м/с     З 7м/с               753  ...                   -8                -3            З         7
10          10       З 11м/с    З 11м/с               738  ...                    0                 2            З        11
11          11        З 8м/с     З 8м/с               732  ...                   -7                -1            З         8
12          12        С 8м/с     С 8м/с               742  ...                  -25               -23            С         8
13          13       СЗ 8м/с    СЗ 8м/с               746  ...                  -27               -26           СЗ         8
14          14       СЗ 6м/с    СЗ 6м/с               753  ...                  -26               -24           СЗ         6
15          15        Ю 7м/с     Ю 7м/с               744  ...                  -19               -22            Ю         7
16          16        В 4м/с     В 4м/с               736  ...                  -20               -17            В         4
17          17       СЗ 8м/с    СЗ 8м/с               750  ...                  -21               -21           СЗ         8
18          18       Ю 10м/с    Ю 10м/с               735  ...                  -17               -17            Ю        10
19          19       СЗ 9м/с    СЗ 9м/с               748  ...                  -16               -11           СЗ         9
20          20       ЮЗ 3м/с    ЮЗ 3м/с               759  ...                  -14               -14           ЮЗ         3
21          21        З 7м/с     З 7м/с               750  ...                    1                 1            З         7
22          22       С 10м/с    С 10м/с               753  ...                  -15               -12            С        10
23          23        С 5м/с     С 5м/с               761  ...                  -17               -15            С         5
24          24        Ю 9м/с     Ю 9м/с               752  ...                   -8               -10            Ю         9
25          25        Ю 8м/с     Ю 8м/с               746  ...                    0                -3            Ю         8

[26 rows x 10 columns]
```

Группируем и считаем сумму:

```
In [6]: df.groupby('Направление')['Скорость'].sum()
Out[6]: 
Направление
В      4
З     47
С     25
СВ     5
СЗ    31
Ш      0
Ю     46
ЮВ    18
ЮЗ     3
Name: Скорость, dtype: int64
```

Примерно то же самое с использованием [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). Применяем к столбцу "Ветер вечером":

```
In [13]: (df['Ветер вечером']
    ...:  .replace({'Ш': 'Ш 0'})
    ...:  .str.extract(r'(?P<Направление>.*) (?P<Скорость>\d+)')
    ...:  .assign(Скорость=lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x['Скорость']))
    ...:  .groupby('Направление').sum()
    ...:  )
Out[13]: 
             Скорость
Направление          
В                   4
З                  47
С                  25
СВ                  5
СЗ                 31
Ш                   0
Ю                  46
ЮВ                 18
ЮЗ                  3
```

Сохраняем результат в словарь:

```
In [17]: wind = df.groupby('Направление')['Скорость'].sum().to_dict()

In [18]: wind
Out[18]: 
{'В': 4,
 'З': 47,
 'С': 25,
 'СВ': 5,
 'СЗ': 31,
 'Ш': 0,
 'Ю': 46,
 'ЮВ': 18,
 'ЮЗ': 3}

In [19]: wind['ЮВ']
Out[19]: 18

In [20]: wind['Ш']
Out[20]: 0
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а можно ли теперь каждое значение скорости закрепить за каждой переменной. Чтобы потом вызвав какую-нибудь переменную, он напечатал ее значение?

Comment: @user449357 Можно положить в словарь. Подойдет такое решение?

Comment: да, можете написать, пожалуйста

Comment: "Ш" - это "штиль", видимо. Думаю, его вообще можно дропнуть в ответе, так как сумма его всегда будет равна 0

Comment: @user449357 если ответ вас устроил, вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить как принятый.

Comment: @user449357 дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, чтобы я без Вас делал, я отметил ответ как полезный, но мой голос не учитывается, поскольку я новичок

Answer (score 0):

Если задача состоит в том чтобы просто вычленить число из строки, то такой код не подойдет?

```
s = pd.Series(["СЗ 5м/с", "В 5м/с", "ЮВ 6м/с"])

s.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Нужно посчитать для каждого направления отдельно. Как это сделать с помощью str.extract , не совсем понимаю